# Controlling brushless motor using ATmega16

Tags: atmega

How can I control a brushless motor using an ATmega16? My motor is of 1600kv and ESC of 30A. I'm giving the 2 sec delay for motor ON and OFF but it's not working.

Comment: That is the point of doing projects, to learn by wiring and coding. What have you found out so far?

Comment: I assume ESC is Electronic Switch Controller ... or something?

Comment: @Spoon ESC is electronic speed controller. It is an MCU subsystem with three-phase inverter, BEMF sensing and control algorithm.

Comment: What have you tried? (Make, Model, Code, any special wiring). (The Grey Beards here are not clairvoyant --- that's not part of the job spec... I just ask the dumb questions.)

Comment: This question requires code and is therefore off-topic.

Comment: I seriously doubt your motor requires 1.6 MV to operate.

Comment: @OlinLathrop the kv constant, that is not kV, is used to measure how much revolution the motor will do per source volt. In this case OP probably meant 1.6kv that means 1600rpm per volt, or with a standard (for RC) 3s1p lipo battery pack (some 14V fully charged) about 1.6*14=22krpm

Answer (score 3):

You will need to talk to the ESC using the appropriate protocol, that is a sort of PWM. Have a look at this Wikipedia article: [Servo control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_control). I would use one of the ATmega timers set on PWM mode, set a frequency of about 50Hz then play around with the duty cycle. This approach is very simple but not much precise since your high time must vary between 1ms (idle) to 2ms (full speed), at 50Hz, i.e. 20ms period, that's between 10% and 5%.